# Undefined property en Foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy iniciando sesión en mi sistema y una vez me logeo, la idea es que el menu se actualice de acuerdo al tipo de perfil del usuario, para lo cual lo estoy haciendo desde la base de datos y mostrando el menú mediante un Foreach. Sin embargo dentro del Foreach, al comparar una de las filas con un numero, es decir, con un id me aparece este mensaje de error y otros similares:

```
Message: Undefined property: mysqli::$id_man
```

Por lo que asumo que no me esta reconociendo el valor de la fila, ¿Por que sucede, como podría corregirlo?

Model

```
public function mostrar_menu(){

$id_tip= $this->session->userdata('tipo');

$this->db->select('id_mc, id_tip, id_man');
$this->db->from('mantenedores_cuenta');
$this->db->where('id_tip',$id_tip);
$menu = $this->db->get();


$horarios ="";
$informes="";


foreach ($menu as $row) {

if ($row->id_man == 1 ) {

$horarios .='<li class="active"><a href="<?= base_url("index.php/C_Horarios"); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Administrar Horarios</a></li>';

} 

if ($row->id_man == 2 ) {

$horarios .='<li><a href="<?= base_url("index.php/C_Calendar"); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Agendar Citas</a></li>';

}

if ($row->id_man == 3 ) {

$horarios .='<li><a href="<?= base_url("index.php/C_Citas"); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Consultar Citas</a></li>';

}

if ($row->id_man == 4 ) {

$informes .='<li class="active"><a href="<?= base_url("index.php/C_Porcentaje"); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Porcentaje de Citas</a></li>';

  }


  } //Fin del Foreach

 $menu_barra=" 

    <ul class='sidebar-menu'>
    <li class='header'>MENU</li>
    <li class='active treeview'>
      <a href='#'>
        <i class='fa fa-fw fa-calendar'></i> <span>Horarios</span>
        <span class='pull-right-container'>
          <i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class='treeview-menu'>
       '$horarios'
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class='treeview'>
     <a href='#'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stats'></span><span>Informes</span> <i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i>
      </a>
      <ul class='treeview-menu'>
        '$informes'
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='documentation/index.html'><i class='fa fa-book'></i> <span>Documentación</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='documentation/index.html'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-sign-out'></i><span>Salir</span></a></li>

  </ul> ";

  return ($menu_barra);

  }
```

Tambien probe por mostrarlo de esta forma, pero no se me permitia en un array o al menos eso decia el mensaje, ejemplo :  $row["id_man"] == 3

Comment: Al hacer `var_dump($row)` que tipo de dato e información te muestra? Normalmente los métodos de SQL de PHP te regresan arreglos, por lo que no podrás acceder a las columnas con `->` ya que no son propiedades de un objeto

Comment: Entonces como podría acceder a la columna?

Comment: `$row[0]['nombre_columna']` ó `$row['nombre_columna'] pero haría falta ver qué te imprime `var_dump($row)`

Comment: El valor de la fila deveria de ser 3 , es decir de esta forma ejemplo $row[3]['id_man'] == 2  sin embargo me arroja este error nuevamente  Cannot use object of type mysqli as array

Comment: El método `get()` de `db` te regresa un objeto de tipo mysqli, te falta hacer el `->fetchAll()` para que te regrese el arreglo

Comment: mmm....no me quedo muy claro, podrías poner un código de ejemplo más completo por favor? He hecho esto antes mediante un while en php nativo, y mostraba los datos de esta forma $datos["id_man"]==1 en el if, pero creo que no es posible usar el while en codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falta es convertir `$menu` en array antes de usarlo en `foreach ($menu as $row)` con `result()`, prueba lo siguiente y me comentas:

```
$menu = $this->db->get();
...
foreach ($menu->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->id_man;
}
```

Saludos.